# Android - Stetho Showing Empty View Hierarchy

Tags: stetho

I initialized stetho with the following code

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
    }
}
```

Now when I go to chrome://inspect it is showing empty View Hierarchy

[image]

However, I can check database in stetho debugger. 
[image]

So, everything else is working fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added android:name=".MyApplication" in the AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag.

It is now working.

```
<application
    ....
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    .....
</application>
```

[image]